# what does `compatible product` mean in product-media.js?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, javascript, magento-community

Can someone explain me what the following code says in `product-media.js` :

```
 getCompatibleProductImages: function(productFallback, selectedLabels) {
        //find compatible products
        var compatibleProducts = [];
        var compatibleProductSets = [];
        selectedLabels.each(function(selectedLabel) {
            if(!productFallback['option_labels'][selectedLabel]) {
                return;
            }

            var optionProducts = productFallback['option_labels'][selectedLabel]['products'];
            compatibleProductSets.push(optionProducts);

            //optimistically push all products
            optionProducts.each(function(productId) {
                compatibleProducts.push(productId);
            });
        });

        //intersect compatible products
        compatibleProductSets.each(function(productSet) {
            compatibleProducts = ConfigurableMediaImages.arrayIntersect(compatibleProducts, productSet);
        });

        return compatibleProducts;
    }
```

What does the `compatible products`  & `intersect compatible products` mean in above code? please someone explain me clearly.